# How can I set YouTube api to fire event ProgressChanged more frequently when uploading video?

Tags: .net, youtube-data-api

I can see there's an event fire for every 10MB uploaded, but I want to get the progress more frequently.

Assume that file's size is smaller than 10MB for example, there will be no progress's information between the start and finish point.

I tried `InsertMediaUpload.GetProgress()` but it only return the uploaded value of ProgressChanged, not the current value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing the `ChunkSize` property on your `InsertMediaUpload` request.

From the [Google API .NET Guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_upload#resumablemediaupload):

> The default chunk size is 10MB, but you can change it by setting the ChunkSize property on the request to any multiple of 256KB.

I tested this using the sample available [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video).

After setting `ChunkSize` in `Run()` with

```
videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = 262144;
```

or

```
videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = ResumableUpload.MinimumChunkSize;
```

I can see that the `videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged` handler is called more frequently.

I thought it might be possible to increase the progress reporting by checking `GetProgress().BytesSent` while the video uploads, but this also only updates after every "chunk" (so the most frequent reporting we can get is that set by `ChunkSize` and caught in the `ProgressChanged` handler).